# How to Search for Record which has external ID is not null?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have a requirement, where I fetch Data from Netsuite using search operators. I do not want Records which have null external ID to be picked.

This is the code used in Transform. What should be done to solve this problem?
Thanks

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    basic: {
        externalId: {
            operator: "ANY_OF",
            searchValue: [{
                externalId: not null
            }]
        },
        lastModifiedDate: {
            operator: "AFTER",
            searchValue: flowVars.lastQueryDateRev
        }
    }
} as :object {
    class : "com.netsuite.webservices.lists.relationships.ContactSearch"
}
```

I expect the server not to pick records which have external ID as null

Comment: I suggest you add a sample json input payload and an expected output json. From there it will make the question more understandable.

Comment: Are you trying to filter the entire record or just the child branch? Can the key externalId occur at various nested levels?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the skipNullOn attribute in the output directive to skip null key:value pairs. You can specify if you want to skip null values of a key:value element, or null  values of an attribute (attributes only apply to XML and DW formatted data, not JSON). The valid values are 'none' (the default), 'elements', 'attributes', or 'everywhere'. The skipNullOn output directive attribute also applies to XML output.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-formats#skip_on_null